# Declare Observable correctly for the list of items

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, ionic4

*.html* // acording to the error problem is on HTML code

```
<ion-card *ngFor="let invitedEvent of invitedEvents">
      <ion-card-content>
         <img [src]="eventPhotoUrl$[invitedEvent.id] | async">
       </ion-card-content>
 </ion-card>
```

*.ts*

```
eventPhotoUrl$: { [id: string]: Observable<SafeResourceUrl> };

ngOnInit(){
 this.eventPhotoUrl$[eventId] = this.photoService.eventPhotoObservable(eventId);
}
```

*photoService.ts*

```
private eventPhotoSubjects: { [id: string]: BehaviorSubject<SafeResourceUrl> } = {};


eventPhotoObservable(eventId: string): Observable<SafeResourceUrl> {

    if (!this.eventPhotoSubjects[eventId]) {
       const eventSubject: BehaviorSubject<SafeResourceUrl> = new BehaviorSubject<SafeResourceUrl>(PhotoPlaceholderPathConstant.EVENT_PHOTO_PLACEHOLDER_URL);
  this.eventPhotoSubjects[eventId] = eventSubject;
  this.afs.doc<ImagePathModel>(`eventDisplayPhotos/${eventId}`).valueChanges()
    .subscribe(async () => {
      const userIdToken: string = await this.auth.getUserIdToken();
      const photoResponse: PhotoResponseModel = await this.getEventPhoto(userIdToken, eventId);
      this.eventPhotoSubjects[eventId].next(this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(photoResponse.dataUrl));
      });
   }
    return this.eventPhotoSubjects[eventId].asObservable();
  }
```

Run time Error: // s68VRWM3T7KZyrrurMyz = eventId

```
HomePage.html:66 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 's68VRWM3T7KZyrrurMyz' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] (HomePage.html:88)
    at Object.debugUpdateRenderer [as updateRenderer] (core.js:39399)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:38382)
    at callViewAction (core.js:38742)
    at execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.js:38699)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:38377)
    at callViewAction (core.js:38742)
    at execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.js:38699)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:38377)
    at callViewAction (core.js:38742)
```

Can you tell me how to declare Observable correctly for the list of items?

Comment: It looks like eventPhotoUrl$ is undefined. Without seeing your code, I guess you didn't initialize your eventPhotoSubjects, did you!?

Comment: @ParrapbanzZ Yes, please see the update.

Comment: Maybe you should initialize `eventPhotoUrl$`? `eventPhotoUrl$ = {}`

Comment: @ParrapbanzZ done. Please see it.

Comment: @AndreiGătej You're right. Such an important tip. I hope you can put it as an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should initialize `eventPhotoUrl$`:

```js
eventPhotoUrl$: { [id: string]: Observable<SafeResourceUrl> } = {};
```